# GroupBy Query over YRBSS Socrata API

Tags: socrata, soda

Need help to build a sample query to get YRBSS 2015 statistics for *questioncode* **H43** and grouped by race. I was following [docs1](https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/chronicdata.cdc.gov/6ay3-nik2) and [doc2](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries/) and was able to get complete data for 2015 by following query:

```
https://chronicdata.cdc.gov/resource/6ay3-nik2.json?$where=(StratificationType='State' OR StratificationType='National')&year=2015&questioncode=H43
```

However $group=race is not working(is this possible? please advice). Any help would be much appreciated.

---

*This question might not look technical but [since support](https://dev.socrata.com/support.html) center suggests to post questions on stack overflow, I'm posting it here*

Answer (score 0):

What was your query using the `$group=race`? You will need to have a [select](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries/select.html) statement and some aggregation function (e.g., count, sum, etc.).

Guessing that you want counts of individual responses by race, this statement will work:

`https://chronicdata.cdc.gov/resource/6ay3-nik2.json?$select=race,count(race)&$where=(StratificationType=%27State%27%20OR%20StratificationType=%27National%27)&questioncode=H43&year=2015&$group=race`

It's preceded by `$select=race,count(race)` to provide counts.